# I want to know that how can I print each letter of my string by using for loop in javascript

Tags: javascript

I can't print each letter of my name

```
     let str = "Ashman"
       console.log(str[0])
     for ( let i = 0 ; str<str.length; i++) {
       console.log(str)
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost correct.

`console.log(str[i])`  should work and `str<str.length` should be `i<str.length`

```js
let str = "Ashman";
for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
  console.log(str[i])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To access each letter you need to insert your console.log(str[0]) inside for loop and change the [0] using your for loop variable.

```js
let str= "Ashman";
for(let i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
  let x = str[i];
  console.log(x)
}
```